# Need driving distance library/application I can talk to

Tags: c#, delphi, routes, gis, distance

We need to calculate driving distances for records in a SQL Server database, so I need to find some sort of library or program that will let me do so without connecting to the internet(if it has it's own database, great, if not, I know where to get data).  I'm not too worried about calculation types right now, we're probably going to go with Djikstra's, but we just need something offline.  Also, I will be dealing with multiple countries, though mostly USA.

So far, I haven't found anything that would work reliably, closest is MapPoint (per Marc Gravell), so I want to ask what offline solutions are available either to plug into, call from, or work next to my code (Delphi and .NET) to calculate driving distances?  Thanks.

Comment: This is assuming you have a database of roads?

Comment: We do have TIGER data in several formats, but was thinking if the solution had it's own database it would be ok.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? Do you have access to Geometry/Geography SQL Server data types?

Comment: We don't have access to those at this point, no.

Comment: @Tom, this is not a real question. You're not clear exactly what you're looking for (SQL, data, a software product, or what), and there's not nearly enough information to be helpful. As it is, the proper answer could be "Buy a GPS", "Buy MapPoint", or several others. Please edit your question to clarify; as is, it will probably be closed.

Comment: @Ken White - I'm not sure how you are finding this unclear.  I specifically stated API in the title, and am asking for offline <programming implied, this is a programming site> solution that I can use with my current code.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry - it's not clear to me. Define "API" in the context you're using it, since you asked for data (or not), but not calculations (maybe), and don't have a DB with SQL Server types for geometry/geography. So what's the "API" if it doesn't calculate and you don't have data? You don't even say what country-am I supposed to look up your profile to see if you're talking about the US, UK, S. America, Europe, or a small city in South Africa? Try this: "I'm looking for something that gets better fuel mileage." Better than what? What fuel? "But I said 'better' - what don't you understand?".

Comment: @Ken: This question is totally clear. And if someone can point out an appropriate API I could use it as well. The API will enable a request that takes two addresses and returns a "driving" distance between these two addresses. Of course, there will be additional parameters and routines, but this is the basic premise. I suspect a web services API woul be the most likely.

Comment: @Ken White - OK, I understand your confusion now.  I have updated my question to hopefully make it better.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks. That actually does look clearer to me. :) I haven't used MapPoint automation for ages (MapPoint 2000, IIRC), but I'll see if I can find anything that might help in my archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after sleeping on the problem, I found a solution by using google to search on "vehicle routing software."  So far I have found three options that look like they might work, and will be investigating them.  Those are ALK Technologies' PCMiler, Telogis' Developer tools, and DNA Evolutions' JOpt.NET.  Still plenty more companies to check out for developer tools on that search phrase.  I think my main problem was I was using "Driving Distance" and "Route distance" as my search terms yesterday.

Edit: for what I'm looking for, Telogis seems to have the most complete function set.

Answer (score 3):

Options:

- For a sensible number of locations, you could obtain (purchase, calculate, etc) a travel matrix between all locations - gets large as you increase the count, though
- If you have the lat/long for each, you can do great-arc quite easily; but tends to get messy near lakes, oceans, etc
- You could use an ***offline*** like MapPoint desktop, perhaps by storing a queue of unknown routes and processing those *outside* the db

Comment: Trying to get mappoint working, but it's giving me a few fits so far, and most of the help I'm fiding is on 2002 or 2004 api, so not sure what has changed. may ask in another question.

Comment: Got MapPoint up and running.  Testing the amount of time, but it seems quite slow so far.

Answer (score 2):

Please check http://www.routeware.dk for RW Net. Developed with Delphi and can use TIGER for off-line calculations. Very fast for large scale matrix calculations.

btw: A better forum for such questions is https://gis.stackexchange.com/